# How to force EditText to accept only numbers?

Tags: android, android-edittext

how to force the EditText to accept only numbers.?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70189238/12272687

Comment: amazing answer :)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use `android:inputType="number"` in your layout XML

Answer (score 63):

This also works fine:

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: very good.Use android:inputType="number" in XML can also input float.

Comment: according to the question, this is supposed to be accepted answer

Answer (score 35):

Or you can add the following:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
                          InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL |
                          InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

this will accept numbers, float point numbers and 
negative numbers you can remove any of these as needed

Answer (score 14):

You can use `android:inputType="number"` in the XML file. You can specify other values such as *numberDecimal* as well.

Also, you might additionally want to use `android:singleLine="true"` for a single line `Edittext`.

Also, look into `android:numeric` and `android:maxLength`. maxLength in particular can be useful for setting length limitations.

Comment: What if my editText appears in the dialog, and thus, I only declare it in .java code? i.e. the dialog editText does not appear in XML file. How can I still achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need support for decimal numbers use this:

```
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution:

```
 public static void enforceEditTextUseNumberOnly(EditText field) {
        Typeface existingTypeface = field.getTypeface();
        field.setInputType((InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD));
        field.setTransformationMethod(new NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod());
        field.setTypeface(existingTypeface);
        if (field.getParent().getParent() instanceof TextInputLayout) {
            ((TextInputLayout) field.getParent().getParent()).setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
        }
    }

  private static class NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
            return source;
        }
    }
```