# How to programmatically set EditText's InputType to integer or decimal?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

How do I programmatically configure an EditText to allow:

> 1. Positive or negative integer values
> 2. Positive or negative decimal values

I am having a hard time finding what gets this working even with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Comment: value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
EditText edt = new EditText(context);
edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); //for decimal numbers
edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED); //for positive or negative values
```

If together:

```
edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |              InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

Answer (score 22):

If someone need, this is the answer in **Kotlin:**

```
et_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED + InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
```

Comment: should be `or` operator not `+`. So proper answer will be `et_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`

Answer (score 5):

In **Kotlin** works little different to Java

```
et_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
et_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
```

Answer (score -8):

You need to add android:inputType="number" in Androidmenifest.xml

Or go to : [How to force EditText to accept only numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334314/how-to-force-edittext-to-accept-only-numbers)

Comment: The OP requested "programatically"