# Display automatically an Integer value from Edit Text (entered by the user) to Text View without any actions (such as onButtonClick) in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

Trying to get an integer from Edit Text entered by the user(such as Total Amount) and to display it by multiplying with value(such as 5%) and display it using TextView automatically.

For the 1st part i.e. simply displaying the integer from EditText to TextView got NumberFormatException Error.

'''
temp = (Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));

textView.setText(temp);

'''

And for the second part i.e. automatically displaying the value from EditText to TextView, no idea how to approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [textwatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) and put the logic in it. Just make sure change the id of `edittext` and `textview`

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String value = s.toString();
        double outputValue = Integer.parseInt(value) * 0.05;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(outputValue));
    }
});
```

Make sure in edittext that it only capture the [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334314/how-to-force-edittext-to-accept-only-numbers) value.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this approach

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String userInputText = s.toString();
        try {
            val userInputAsNumbger = userInputText.toInt();
        }catch (e:NumberFormatException){
            print(e.message)
        }
        }
    });
```

to ensure it doesn't error